# Weird crash error on iPhone

Tags: xcode, ios5

I am working on my first iPhone app it has been running well so far, but suddenly it started crashing and I kept getting this error:

> 2012-08-13 08:39:50.000 OGLGame[36085:10a03] -[**NSCFString
>   setFrame:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7368300
>   2012-08-13 08:39:50.031 OGLGame[36085:10a03] (    0   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x0166203e __exceptionPreprocess + 206    1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x01c7fcd6 objc_exception_throw + 44  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x01663cbd -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 253    3
>
>   CoreFoundation                      0x015c8ed0 __*forwarding*** + 432
>     4   CoreFoundation                      0x015c8cb2
>   _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50    5   OGLGame                             0x00004673 -[EAGLView setupScore] + 355     6   OGLGame
>   0x0000335b -[EAGLView initGame] + 299     7   OGLGame
>   0x00003217 -[EAGLView initWithCoder:] + 1047  8   UIKit
>   0x00a48135 -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 243     9   UIKit
>   0x00b47c6e UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 2276    10  UIKit
>   0x00b47383 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 117  11  UIKit
>   0x00a47cad -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 187    12  UIKit
>   0x00b47c6e UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 2276    13  UIKit
>   0x00b4767b UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 753     14  UIKit
>   0x00b47383 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 117  15  UIKit
>   0x00a47105 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 817   16  UIKit
>   0x00a48eb7 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions)
>   loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 157    17  UIKit
>   0x00825ce1 -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFileNamed:bundle:] + 58    18 
>   UIKit                               0x00825ff8 -[UIApplication
>   _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 225     19  UIKit                               0x0082517f -[UIApplication
>   _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 279  20  UIKit                               0x00834183 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1027    21  UIKit                               0x00834c38 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68     22  UIKit
>   0x00828634 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 8196   23  GraphicsServices
>   0x03af7ef5 PurpleEventCallback + 1274     24  CoreFoundation
>   0x01636195 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION**
>   + 53  25  CoreFoundation                      0x0159aff2 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146   26  CoreFoundation                      0x015998da __CFRunLoopRun + 2218    27  CoreFoundation
>   0x01598d84 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212     28  CoreFoundation
>   0x01598c9b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123   29  UIKit
>   0x00824c65 -[UIApplication _run] + 576    30  UIKit
>   0x00826626 UIApplicationMain + 1163   31  OGLGame
>   0x000029c4 main + 116     32  OGLGame
>   0x00002945 start + 53     33  ???
>   0x00000001 0x0 + 1 )

Here is the function that I believe is throwing the error:

> -(void) setupScore{
>
> ```
> scoreLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"foo"];
> scoreLabel.frame = CGRectMake(262, 250, 100, 40);
> [scoreLabel setText: scoreString];
>
> //normally you'll want a transparent background for your label
> scoreLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
>
> //you can use non-standard fonts
> [scoreLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"TimesNewRoman" size: 1.0f]];
>
> //change the label's text color
> scoreLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
>
> //you can even create a drop shadow on your label text
> /*myLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6;   
>  myLabel.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0;
>  myLabel.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
>  myLabel.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0);*/
>
> //add it to your view
> scoreLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(89.53);
> [self addSubview:scoreLabel];  }
> ```
>
> -(void) resetScore {
>       score = 0;
>       scoreLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
>       [scoreLabel release]; }
>
> -(void)drawScore{
>       [scoreLabel setText: scoreString]; }

Does anyone know how to fix this weird crash?

Let me know if you need more code, Thank You!

Comment: The issue is that your app has caused an exception to be thrown, and it doesn't catch the exception. You should tell the debugger to stop on exceptions (Objective-C and C++, but this one is Objective-C) and see which line of code is throwing the exception. That's where your error is.

Comment: Sorry I am new to all this, so how would I do that?

Comment: See [this page](http://ijoshsmith.com/2011/11/28/debugging-exceptions-in-xcode-4-2/) for info on how to turn them on.

Comment: So I tried that, and it keeps pointing to the "int retVal" line of code and I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Check out my answer on this question to get an NSLog of the offending line's call stack (then post it here): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462939/xcode-4-x-making-it-point-to-the-offending-crashing-line/11463116#11463116

Comment: note that in your app, wrap the `int retVal = UIApplicationMain...` line in the `@try` block (instead of the `return ...` line in my example)

Comment: Sorry what do you mean ctrahey?

Comment: and I tried nesting it in the try catch, but I think that I did it wrong, so how would I do that correctly?

Comment: Okay, can you post the code for `[EAGLView setupScore]`? There is likely an improper alloc/init sequence in there.

Comment: Based on the code in your comments on an answer below (which should be added to your question), can you please show how `scoreString` from `[scoreLabel setText: scoreString];` is created/initialized?

Comment: Can you also show the @interface portion that defines these properties? There is probably some mistreatment of NSString as a UILabel here.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the stack you posted, It is likely that there is a place inside `[EAGLView setupScore]` where you are assigning a variable to be something (likely an `NSString`) with just `alloc`, and not assigning the return of it's `init` method to the same var.

```
// this is WRONG!!
NSString *aString = [NSString alloc];
[aString initWithFormat:@"foo"];

// this is correct
NSString *aString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"foo"];

// even better
NSString *aString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"foo"];
// (class methods named in this manner (start with name of class) 
// take care of alloc and init for you)
```

The reason is that init methods are allowed to return a completely different pointer than alloc returns, and this new pointer is valid, the old one is not. **always** nest your alloc/init calls this way.

## edit

Based on some info you posted in a comment on another answer, it looks like the call `[scoreLabel setText: scoreString];` inside `-(void) setupScore` is using an improperly retained NSString object via `scoreString`.

My guess is that the @property for that string is declared to be weak, or else you are not properly initializing it anywhere.

## edit 2

You have some improper handling of the scoreLabel and scoreString variables. In one place, you are setting your scoreLabel property to be an NSString. You likely intend to do:

```
scoreString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"foo"];
```

Then, you are assuming that `scoreLabel` exists, but in one of your other methods you explicitly release it. This means that you need to check here for it properly existing, and create a new one if needed.

Comment: I've edited this answer to reflect what I think is going on based on that update. Thanks!

Comment: ok, so i changed that, but now the app crashed again with another warning.

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant code (anything related to that string) and any updated errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is probably accessing invalid memory. This happens frequntly when an object is deallocated and used afterwards. You can turn on zombie detection to deterct these cases.

Answer (score -1):

The stacktrace shows that you're using an own view, `EAGLView`, which calls a method `setupScore` during initialization. Line 340 here causes the crash.

How does this method look like?

Comment: Questions such as these are good for the comments area under the original question.

Comment: -(void) setupScore{
    
    scoreLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(262, 250, 100, 40)];
    [scoreLabel setText: scoreString];
    
    //normally you'll want a transparent background for your label
    scoreLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Comment: //you can use non-standard fonts
    [scoreLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"TimesNewRoman" size: 1.0f]];
    
    //change the label's text color
    scoreLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    
    //you can even create a drop shadow on your label text
    /*myLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6;   
     myLabel.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0;
     myLabel.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
     myLabel.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0);*/
    
    //add it 
    scoreLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(89.53);
    [self addSubview:scoreLabel]; 
}

Comment: Line 340 is a white space line after the end of my setup score method.